# R: iterative constrained portfolio optimization

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, portfolio

I am trying to construct the minimum variance portfolio from a large set of stocks (890), which also satisfies some additional external constraints. For example I want to check whether the resulting portfolio meets certain sector weight restrictions and if it does not then look for new one that does.

Here is the code I am currently using to find the minimum variance portfolio (using cov.shrink from the corpcor package and solve.QP from the quadprog package):

```
X <- as.matrix(LogReturn)

# Shrinkage estimator covariance matrix
covar <- cov.shrink(X)

N <- ncol(X)
zeros <- array(0, dim = c(N,1))

# Evaluate the optimization to generate minimum variance portfolio with no short selling and with max allocation of 0.05
aMat <- cbind(1, diag(N))
aMat <- cbind(aMat, -diag(N))

b0 <- c(1, rep(0, N))
b0 <- c(b0, rep(-0.05, N))

res <- solve.QP(covar, zeros, aMat, bvec=b0, meq = 1)

# Return portfolio attributes
y <- X %*% res$solution
port <- list(pw = round(res$solution,3), px = y, pm = mean(y), ps = sd(y))
port
```

And here is the code I planned to use to check whether the proposed portfolio meets my sector constraints:

```
Sedol <- cbind(SedolData, round(res$solution,3))
colnames(Sedol) <- c("SEDOL", "Sector", "Country", "Weight")

# Proposed sector data
L <- nrow(SectorKey)
Sector <- cbind(SectorKey, 0)
colnames(Sector) <- c("Name", "Key", "Parent", "Proposed")
bPass <- TRUE
for(i in 1:L){
  for (x in 1:N){
    if(Sedol[x,2] == Sector[i,2]){
      Sector[i,4] <- Sector[i,4] + Sedol[x,4]
    }
  }  
  if(abs(Sector[i,3] - Sector[i,4])>0.05){
    bPass <- FALSE
  }
}

if(bPass == FALSE){
  # add cost function?
}
```

I am quite new to r and I was wondering whether someone could suggest how I should proceed. I was thinking I would iteratively penalise portfolios that do not satisfy my constraints with some sort of cost function, but as I do not how to solve my problem without using solve.QP I am not sure how to go about this.

LogReturns is a matrix of log returns for my 890 stocks with 120 observations.
SedolData is a key for which sector each stock is in and used to find the allocations of the proposed portfolio to each sector (matrix of 890 stocks with key for each sector in column two).
SectorKey is a matrix of sectors with target weights (tolerance 5%).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: QP solvers (including Quadprog) allow linear constraints. So the best way forward is to add your restrictions as linear constraints. Consult the Quadprog documentation for the correct format.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Do you think that constraints of this nature can be incorporated? I have added no short selling and max allocation constraints, but I am confused how to add more complicated constraints. The main documentation does not give much detail, is there anywhere else you can recommend looking?

Comment: It often helps to first develop a mathematical model and once that looks reasonable to implement for solving it with a solver. I believe your sector restrictions are linear, but writing it down in math is an easy way to confirm.